# Android apk detected as threat

Tags: android, apk, antivirus

After installing an application developed by me, Avast anti virus detects it as virus. I checked the following things

1. Debugable is false
2. proguard is activated
3. app is signed properly from keystore
4. Using allowable permissions and No private permission used in manifest

Please suggest what else I need to do.

Comment: deinstall avast anti virus?

Comment: Not really a help if he wants his app to look legit to his customers

Answer (score 3):

Avast has a form on their website where you can submit your APK file (or other program file) along with an explanation of the problem so that they can look into it.

https://www.avast.com/false-positive-file-form.php

Avast also recommends uploading the file to VirusTotal - a site which checks files against the software of a number of different malware vendors.

https://www.virustotal.com/